# How can i load data from a hive table on an external network to Amazon Redshift?

Tags: amazon-web-services, hadoop, hive, amazon-redshift

I need some suggestions here to load data from a external hive table on an external network to Amazon RedShift. The hive is totally like a separate entity on an external network and i need to make it available in the Amazon Redshift.

Comment: Use s3? Write from Hive to S3 & load RedShift from s3.

Answer (score 0):

The Basic here is that you would need internet connectivity If your Hive in on-premise. One possible approach is as follows :
1. Mount your S3 to your Hadoop Environment.
2. Create the Hive DDL compatible with for Red-shift only then you will be able to write to Redshift.